# How can you create a Project Sheet in SmartSheets with the API

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I'm a new user of the SmartSheets API, attempting to create an integration.  I have projects that are created in an external system that I wish to represent in a Project Sheet in SmartSheets, but in my attempts so far using the SmartSheets API, all I can create is a simple grid.  Is there an API that will allow me to create a Project Sheet in SmartSheets?

Answer (score 0):

A project sheet seems to be a regular sheet with a Gant View activated [Smarsheet Sheet object documentation](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/sheetsObjects#section/Sheet-Object)

When you create the sheet object, make sure you activate the boolean option "ganttEnabled" or "gant_enabled" to True.

```
# from documentation Sample 1: Create sheet in folder
sheet_spec = smartsheet.models.Sheet({
  'name': 'newsheet',
  'columns': [{
  'title': 'Favorite',
  'type': 'CHECKBOX',
  'symbol': 'STAR'
  }, {
  'title': 'Primary Column',
  'primary': True,
  'gant_enabled': True,
  'type': 'TEXT_NUMBER'
  }
]
})
response = smartsheet_client.Folders.create_sheet_in_folder(3734419270854532,      
sheet_spec)
new_sheet = response.result
```

After testing this option I found that the object has the properties, but the API fails to create the object, so an alternative solution was,

1. Manually create a project
2. Manually create a template from the project (Save as Template)
3. use the API to create a sheet using the template

   ```
   import smartsheet
   smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
   smart.errors_as_exceptions(True)

   fldr = <folder ID>
   temp = <Template ID>

   sht_spec = smart.models.Sheet({'name': 'sht_name', 'from_id': temp})

   response = smart.Folders.create_sheet_in_folder(fldr,sht_spec)
   new_sht = response.result
   ```

Comment: Hmmmmm.  This does not work for me.  And documentation that I see at https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/tag/sheets#operation/create-sheet-in-folder does not list `ganttEnabled` or `gant_Enabled` or anything similar as being acceptable in the column array.  The error I get when I try to specify either of those is
        {
  "errorCode" : 1008,
  "message" : "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Unknown attribute \"gantt_enabled\" found at  line 1, column 103",
  "refId" : "1ma0w2gcii4iq"
}

Comment: I found an alternative solution, this time I tested, if you create a project template and then create a sheet using the template it will create a project object
 `import smartsheet 
smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()
smart.errors_as_exceptions(True)

fldr = 8107727340758916
temp = 345898388612996

sht_spec = smart.models.Sheet({
    'name': 'deleteme', 'from_id': temp
})`

It seems like the sheet creation although the object has the option, the command fails to create it.

Comment: Yes, I had found this solution as well.  But the problem for me is the step 1 and step 2 both starting with "Manual".  My specification is to make this 100% automated, and applicable to any SmartSheets installation.  I think there is no API to create templates.  I was able to create a project sheet by viewing the available "global" templates and selecting the id out of that, but this is a terrible programming option, because it requires listing all the public templates (100s of them) and then iterating through them to find a good candidate for the generic project template.  Really messy!

Comment: Agreed 100%, There is so many missing pieces in the API that it is frustrating, in fact I think that is the reason why there is so few people using it, but in my case I have no choice and do the best I can with it, good luck with your development.

Answer (score 0):

You can autonomate the full process:

- have a project sheet sitting somewhere for a system account you own.
- share the sheet to the desired account (as viewer)
- copy the sheet with that second (the second account is now the woner of the sheet)
- unshare the first sheet (no longer needed)

Comment: Thank you for weighing in.  This looks like a great way to accomplish the task, but my particular specification is to do this via the API.  Which sadly appears not to be possible!

Comment: All these  but the first task can be done through the API.